# Is there anything I can use other than alert to tell the user the hex code was copied?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am wondering if there is something that I can use instead of `alert('Copied the hex value '+copyHex.value)` to tell the user the message was copied? I don't like the way alert interrupts the page. I was wondering if 'copied (hex code)' who fade in above the color? I think this would look the best.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
    Color Generator 
</title>
<style>
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #161818;
    font-family: "Consolas";
}
.color{
    margin-top: 300px;
    text-align: center;
}
#hex{
    display: block;
    color: white;
    font-size: 100px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0px;
}
.color button{
    background: none;
    outline: 10px;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 20px;
    border: 3px solid white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="color">
        <span id="hex">#??????</span>
        <button onclick="genNewColor()">Generate new random color</button>
        <button onclick="copyHexValue()">Copy hex value</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function genNewColor() {
  var symbols, color;
  symbols = "0123456789ABCDEF";

  color = "#";
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color = color + symbols[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)]
  }
  document.body.style.background = color;
  document.getElementById("hex").innerHTML = color;
    }

    function copyHexValue() {
  var copyHex = document.createElement('input');
   copyHex.value = document.getElementById("hex").innerHTML;
   document.body.appendChild(copyHex);
   copyHex.select();
   document.execCommand('copy');
   alert('Copied the hex value '+copyHex.value)
   console.log('Copied the hex value '+copyHex.value)
   document.body.removeChild(copyHex);    
}
    document.body.onkeyup = function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 32){}
    
}


    
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a div with your custom message to notify your user.

I added an empty Notification div in your HTML and a CSS class for the same,
and removed `alert("Copied the hex value " + copyHex.value);`
Instead called a function to show the Notification

The Notification will appear at the top and will slide out after 2s (setTimeout)

PS Run the code snippet in full screen and if you want to outsource this try [Material.io](https://material.io/components/snackbars#usage)

Good Luck

```js
    function genNewColor() {
        var symbols, color;
        symbols = "0123456789ABCDEF";

        color = "#";
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            color = color + symbols[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
        }
        document.body.style.background = color;
        document.getElementById("hex").innerHTML = color;
    }

    function copyHexValue() {
        var copyHex = document.createElement("input");
        copyHex.value = document.getElementById("hex").innerHTML;
        document.body.appendChild(copyHex);
        copyHex.select();
        document.execCommand("copy");
        // alert("Copied the hex value " + copyHex.value);
        showNotification(copyHex.value);

        console.log("Copied the hex value " + copyHex.value);
        document.body.removeChild(copyHex);
    }

    document.body.onkeyup = function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 32) {
        }
    };

    const notification = document.querySelector(".notification");

    function showNotification(color) {
        let notificationText;
      // If no color has been picked 
        if (color === "#??????") notificationText = "Generate a color first";
      // Show Color Picked Message
        else notificationText = `Copied hex value ${color}`;
      //Slide down the notification
        notification.style.transform = "translate(-50%,100%)";
      // Add message to notification
        notification.textContent = notificationText;

    //Make Notification slide back up after 2s
        setTimeout(function hideNotification() {
            notification.style.transform = "translate(-50%,-100%)";
        }, 2000);
    }
```

```css
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background: #161818;
        font-family: "Consolas";
    }
    .color {
        margin-top: 300px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #hex {
        display: block;
        color: white;
        font-size: 100px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        margin: 0px;
    }
    .color button {
        background: none;
        outline: 10px;
        color: white;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 20px;
        border: 3px solid white;
    }

    .notification {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 0;
        transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
        transition: transform 0.6s ease;
        border: 2px solid white;
        padding: 12px 30px;
        color: white;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <title>
            Color Generator
        </title>
        

    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="color">
            <span id="hex">#??????</span>
            <button onclick="genNewColor()">Generate new random color</button>
            <button onclick="copyHexValue()">Copy hex value</button>
        </div>

        <div class='notification'>

        </div>

        

    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways to do this. One of the simplest would be to add a DOM element above the hex and have it set to `display:none;` using a class called `hidden`

You could then set a timeout to show the element for a short time instead of an alert.

```
    document.getElementById("hex-copy").classList.remove("hidden");
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.getElementById("hex-copy").classList.add("hidden");
    }, 2500);
```

For a fade in, you could set CSS animations on the element.